# How do I call the injected dependency 'level' and use it as a condition in an IF statement? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.level'

```cs
public Form1( int level ) {
    this.level = level;
    playtune();
    InitializeComponent();
}
// the value is actually 1 and the 0 is just to declare the variable
int level = 0;

static void playtune()
{
    SoundPlayer tune = new SoundPlayer(
        GameProject.Properties.Resources.level_audio_mario);
    if (level == 2)
    {
        tune = new SoundPlayer(GameProject.Properties.Resources.level_audio_sonic);
    }
    tune.Play();
}
```

Comment: Your question needs more details and clarity. It's unclear what it is you are trying to achieve. For instance why would calling `new Form1(1)` and `new Form1(2)` not be sufficient?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your method to non static?

```
static void playtune()
```

=>

```
    void playtune()
    {
        SoundPlayer tune = new SoundPlayer(GameProject.Properties.Resources.level_audio_mario);
        if (this.level == 2)
        {
            tune = new SoundPlayer(GameProject.Properties.Resources.level_audio_sonic);
        }
        tune.Play();
    }
```